# Will compute nodes with A100 80GB (2x on node1) and A100 40GB (2x on node2) work in Red Hat OpenShift cluster?

Tags: infrastructure, nvidia, gpu, analytics, openshift

I think the answer should be yes, however these parts/cards are expensive, so would like to know from experts who have done this kind of things.

Will MIG be supported on this?